# <tr> will not centre

Tags: html, css

The items in my table are not center. I'm still a beginner and know that it is bad practice to use tables these days but I feel I should start from the beginning. I have 2 items that I would like to center in the middle of the screen in the same row. Currently, the images are to the left.

```
<table>
  <tr align="center">
  <td>
    <a href="http://sourceforge.net/">
      <img src="Resource/download.png">
    </a>
 </td>

 <td>
   <a href="http://sourceforge.net/">
     <img src="Resource/info.png">
   </a>
 </td>

 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables aren't the "beginning", they're still useful, just not for what you think. Tables should be used to display **tabular data**, nothing more. If you need to build a layout that's similar to a table, use the appropriate display properties on correct markup instead.

Answer (score 4):

Just going to post this as a seperate answer, because of how horrible the convention to use attributes for styling is. Don't **ever** use attributes for styling. See [**the MDN attributes list**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Attributes). See all those thumbs down next to the attribute name? They mean: '**Don't use this attribute**'. It does still work, but it's just horrible. Like using deprecated tags like `center`, using deprecated attributes is just really bad habit. The MDN article mentions how to achieve the same thing as what you'd do with the attribute, but without the deprecated HTML.

In this situation, use:

```
<table style="width:100%;border:1px solid black;">
```

and:

```
<tr style="text-align:center;">
```

The final fiddle would be [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hvP72/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Jatin gave you a solution, but he didn't explain it.  Your `align` attribute is set properly and it's working, but the table is only as wide as its contents.  The text is centered within the table as you intended, but the table itself isn't centered.  Since the table is left-justified by default, it looks like it's not centered.

Especially as a beginner, you should try to do things the right way.  It'll be much easier for you later if you adopt good practices early.  A table is the wrong thing for what you're trying to do.

An important habit to get into is to put only your content, like text and pictures, into the HTML and put all the code that controls how it looks into CSS.  Although the `align` property is valid (in HTML 4), it means you're putting something that controls the appearance into the HTML.  The same goes for the `border` and `width` properties.

This is how you should control the appearance of a table:

#### HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="http://sourceforge.net/"><img src="Resource/download.png"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://sourceforge.net/"><img src="Resource/info.png"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
table {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

A better way might be like this:

#### HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

#### CSS

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you wanted to center more than just a couple of links, you may want to put it into a block or a paragraph.

I put something up on CodePen that shows a few examples of how to accomplish this: http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/iaEvh

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/hvP72/)

Small Change:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
```

Comment: Wow, the tutorial did not have width = 100%. Thank you.

Comment: NO! Don't use attributes for styling! Use `style="width:100%;border:1px solid black;"` for this. These attributes are obsolete.

Comment: @Joeytje50 he specified that he's learning from the beginning. He'll get to the CSS later, I think he's in HTML at the moment so rather than confuse him I think the answer accurately demonstrates that the didn't LOOK centered because the table itself is smashed over to the side.

Comment: @leigero No, I am going to have to disagree. If you're going to learn a skill, you're not going to start the slightly easier, but COMPLETELY wrong way of doing it. If you're going to learn how to pitch with baseball by first learning a football-like toss, then the bad throwing habit will stick, and it's MUCH harder to learn another way.

Comment: I'm not sure what parts of maths you're referring to, but either your school just sucks, or those things are being taught to make you understand how a mathematical rule works, before moving on to the easier way. This does what's basically the opposite: it shows the way it's not supposed to work to demonstrate how something could work by exploiting backwards compatibility of browsers, and then afterwards it lets you learn the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: Although I agree that it's bad practice to mix presentation and content the way you do if you use attributes for styling, Jatin provided a simple and accurate answer to the original poster's question.  I just would have added an explanation.

Comment: @Joe Which tutorial are you following?  We may be able to provide some constructive comments or even a better tutorial.  Also, don't be put off by the intensity of some people's comments.  You're doing well.  We just feel very strongly about doing things the right way and don't necessarily always agree about what that is :)

Comment: @Ghodmode I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fS7w-TXinPE and now I'm moving on to CSS. I feel like I should know all the perks to a language before moving to the next even though it may be better practice to use CSS for styling. If you have better tutorials I'd gladly follow them. Thanks for caring.